# Copying the data to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Here i have developed one macro which supposed to copy data from sheet "Output Table" to "Output Format - Americas" in mentioned specific cells, my code is running but not giving any output and no error also please help me on this.

```
Sub Copy_Deals_To_Report()
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsReport As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim regionCol As Long
    Dim strategyCol As Long
    Dim assetCol As Long
    Dim statusCol As Long
    Dim outputRow1 As Long
    Dim outputRow2 As Long
    
    ' Set the worksheets
    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output Table")
    Set wsReport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output Format - Americas")
    
    ' Find the column numbers
    regionCol = wsData.Range("A1:R1").Find("Region", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
    strategyCol = wsData.Range("A1:R1").Find("Strategy", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
    assetCol = wsData.Range("A1:R1").Find("Asset Group", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
    statusCol = wsData.Range("A1:R1").Find("Deal Status", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
    
    ' Loop through the rows and copy the matching ones to the report sheet
    outputRow1 = 11 ' Start from row 11 in the report sheet for the first criteria
    outputRow2 = 513 ' Start from row 17 in the report sheet for the second criteria
    For i = 2 To wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' Assuming data starts from row 2
        If wsData.Cells(i, regionCol).Value = "Americas" And _
           wsData.Cells(i, strategyCol).Value = "BREIT" And _
           wsData.Cells(i, assetCol).Value = "Logistics" And _
           wsData.Cells(i, statusCol).Value = "Requires Immediate Attention" Then
            wsData.Range("F" & i & ":R" & i).Copy wsReport.Range("A" & outputRow1 & ":M" & outputRow1)
            outputRow1 = outputRow1 + 1
        ElseIf wsData.Cells(i, regionCol).Value = "Americas" And _
           wsData.Cells(i, strategyCol).Value = "" And _
           wsData.Cells(i, assetCol).Value = "Logistics" And _
           wsData.Cells(i, statusCol).Value = "On the Market" Then
            wsData.Range("F" & i & ":R" & i).Copy wsReport.Range("A" & outputRow2 & ":M" & outputRow2)
            outputRow2 = outputRow2 + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: 1.) You are using column `A` to determine the last row. If it is empty (except for the first cell), the last row will be `1` and the loop from `2 To 1` will never be entered. 2.) You are using `And` which means that **all 4 criteria** have to be met. Maybe you meant **any of the 4 criteria** when you should have used `Or` instead. Let us know if the cause is one of these reasons. If not, I'll take a closer look.

Comment: `Dim regionCol as Range` `Dim strategyCol as Range`  `Dim assetCol as Range`  `Dim statusCol as Range` then use `regionCol.Column` `strategyCol.Column` `assetCol.Column` `statusCol.Column`

Comment: I would suggest you use the debugger and step thru the code to check what is going on. Is the loop entered at all? If yes: What is `i` when the `copy` is issued.